# How to upload large files to amazon s3 using curl

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I use this bash script to upload a relatively large file to AMAZON S3:

```
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -m 6000 -S -v -X PUT -T "${file}" \
    -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
    -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
    https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

Most of the times it works properly, but sometimes it fails giving this kind of errors:

```
[...]
28  768M    0     0   28  222M      0  8851k  0:01:28  0:00:25  0:01:03 7870k* SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

30  768M    0     0   30  231M      0  9013k  0:01:27  0:00:26  0:01:01 9819k
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

How can i retry the upload until it is loaded without errors ?

```
curl -V
```

gives:

```
curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 c-ares/1.10.0 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.6.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets Metalink
```

and it should be the latest version.

Comment: Is there perhaps something in your setup (outside of curl) that times out after a minute?

Comment: @DanielStenberg you may be onto something.  The `errno 104` is "Connection reset by peer," which would be either the far end (S3 itself) or an intermediate piece of stateful network hardware forcibly closing the connection.

Comment: why using curl and not the aws cli with multipart upload? do you have a constraint on this?